# Semi_join to filter columns of X based on multiple Y columns

Tags: r, dplyr, semi-join

Starting with these two data frames:

```
data <- data.frame("Run_ID" = c(1,2,3), "Sample" = c("A", "B", "C"), "Value" = c(1,2,3))
metadata <- data.frame("Run_ID" = c(1,3), "Sample" = c("A","C"))
```

I would like to subset `data` so that it only includes the values from the pairs of `Run_ID` + `Sample` which also are present in `metadata`. The output should contain the same columns as `data`.

Expected Output:

```
Run_ID Sample Value
1      A     1
3      C     3
```

Based on the documentation, it seems like `semi_join()` should be the solution, but I cannot figure out join based on the two variables.

```
>semi_join(data, metadata, by = c("Run_ID", "Sample"))
[1] Run_ID Sample Value 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok but the input `metadata` is not in a friendly format but I guess this is what you're after:

```
semi_join(
  data,
  metadata %>% separate_rows(Sample, sep = ','), 
  by = c('Run_ID', 'Sample')
)
#   Run_ID Sample Value
# 1      1      A     1
# 2      3      C     3
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I realized that there was a typo in the "Sample" metadata column, which I now fixed... Was that what you were referring in terms of formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
metadata %>% separate_rows(Sample) %>% inner_join(data)
Joining, by = c("Run_ID", "Sample")
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Run_ID Sample Value
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1      1 A          1
2      3 C          3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works somewhat, but `inner_join()` also adds extra columns to the output if they are present in `metadata`. I would like that the output only returns the columns that were in `data` originally.

Comment: @bgfritz1, you can use `select` to select the columns that you need. Just add `%>% select(col1, col2, col3..)` at the end of the above code